# Iphone: which event is called when a view is unloaded?

Tags: iphone, view

The question is all in the title. I want to execute some cleanup code when one view in my application gets unloaded. Is it possible to do so? If so, which is the event that I should intercept?

Answer (score 1):

[-viewDidUnload()](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/viewDidUnload) or [-viewWillDisappear()](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/viewWillDisappear:) depending on your design. You probably want to go for viewDidUnload().

Comment: viewDidUnload() is only called if the view controller receives a memory warning, its view is not being displayed *and* it handles memory warnings in the default way (by just passing it to its parent class). This makes viewDidUnload() actually a bad place to do clean-up that may need to be done often. It will either need to be done on dealloc or a method may need to be added to do clean-up of critical resources.

Answer (score 1):

It will also depend on the sdk you are using. If you are using iphone-sdk 3.x then `viewDidUnload` will be called otherwise it will not get called. while `viewWillDisappear` is called in 2.x and above. Now still if you want to call a method only when the view is unloaded you can call it from the `dealloc` but it will not be highly trustable.

Comment: viewDidUnload is rarely called. For instance, if the view controller is simply deallocated, viewDidUnload will *not* be called. It is only called if the parent view unloads a view controller's view and the view controller itself is not deallocated.

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to take a look at viewDidUnload or viewWillDisappear, for cleanup you'll probably use viewDidUnload, you may also want to just do cleanup in the dealloc method.

From Apple's documentation:

> viewDidUnload Called when the
>   controller’s view is released from
>   memory.

```
- (void)viewDidUnload
```

> Discussion This method is called as a
>   counterpart to the viewDidLoad method.
>   It is called during low-memory
>   conditions when the view controller
>   needs to release its view and any
>   objects associated with that view to
>   free up memory. Because view
>   controllers often store references to
>   views and other view-related objects,
>   you should use this method to
>   relinquish ownership in those objects
>   so that the memory for them can be
>   reclaimed. You should do this only for
>   objects that you can easily recreate
>   later, either in your viewDidLoad
>   method or from other parts of your
>   application. You should not use this
>   method to release user data or any
>   other information that cannot be
>   easily recreated.
>
> Typically, a view controller stores
>   references to objects using an outlet,
>   which is a variable or property that
>   includes the IBOutlet keyword and is
>   configured using Interface Builder. A
>   view controller may also store
>   pointers to objects that it creates
>   programmatically, such as in the
>   viewDidLoad method. The preferred way
>   to relinquish ownership of any object
>   (including those in outlets) is to use
>   the corresponding accessor method to
>   set the value of the object to nil.
>   However, if you do not have an
>   accessor method for a given object,
>   you may have to release the object
>   explicitly. For more information about
>   memory management practices, see
>   Memory Management Programming Guide
>   for Cocoa.
>
> By the time this method is called, the
>   view property is nil.
>
> Special Considerations If your view
>   controller stores references to views
>   and other custom objects, it is also
>   responsible for relinquishing
>   ownership of those objects safely in
>   its dealloc method. If you implement
>   this method but are building your
>   application for iPhone OS 2.x, your
>   dealloc method should release each
>   object but should also set the
>   reference to that object to nil before
>   calling super.
>
> viewWillDisappear: Notifies the view
>   controller that its view is about to
>   be dismissed, covered, or otherwise
>   hidden from view.

```
- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
```

> Parameters animated If YES, the
>   disappearance of the view is being
>   animated.
>
> Discussion This method is called in
>   response to a view being removed from
>   its window or covered by another view.
>   This method is called before the view
>   is actually removed or covered and
>   before any animations are configured.
>
> Subclasses can override this method
>   and use it to commit editing changes,
>   resign the first responder status of
>   the view, or perform other relevant
>   tasks. For example, you might use this
>   method to revert changes to the
>   orientation or style of the status bar
>   that were made in the
>   viewDidDisappear: method when the view
>   was first presented. If you override
>   this method, you must call super at
>   some point in your implementation.